# inner Join entre 2 tablas con base de datos distintas POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, transact-sql

Buenas estoy realizando una consulta para construir una tabla hecho en Postgresql.
Pero me encuentro con este inconveniente, estoy tratando de consultar a dos tablas que se encuentran en diferentes base de datos, pero tienen el mismo tipo de id.

```
Select t1.campo1 , t2.campo2 from public.tabla1 as t1
inner join as public.tabla2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

En SQL, despues del inner join hacia refencia de esta manera: [BaseDatos].tabla1

Mi consulta que estoy construyendo:

```
select t.idtrabajador ,
        dim_dep.idarea, 
SUM(case when  com.con_tipo='1' then 1 else 0 end) as totalMeritos,
SUM(case when  com.con_tipo='2' then 1 else 0 end) as totalActivos,
SUM(case when  com.con_tipo='3' then 1 else 0 end) as totalRehabilitados,
SUM(case when  com.con_tipo='5' then 1 else 0 end) as totalInformativos,
SUM(case when  com.con_tipo='6' then 1 else 0 end) as totalEximir,
COUNT(com.con_tipo) as totalRegistro
from escalafon.trabajador t
inner join escalafon.comportamiento com on com.idtrabajador=t.idtrabajador
left join patrimonio.area ar on ar.idarea = t.idarea
left join patrimonio.sede sd on sd.idsede = t.idsede  
left join public.dim_departamento dim_dep
on substring(dim_dep.idarea, 3) = ar.idestructura :: text and dim_dep.sed_descripcion = dim_dep.sede 
group by t.idtrabajador , dim_dep.idarea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En PostgreSQL no puedes hacer el llamado a una tabla de otra base de datos como lo haces en SQL Server, para eso debes usar tablas foráneas con  los FDW , en la documentación oficial: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/postgres-fdw.html

puede ser algo como esto en tu caso:

```
    CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;


    CREATE SERVER servidor
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
    OPTIONS (host 'localhost', port '5432', dbname 'basedatos_otra');


    CREATE USER MAPPING FOR PUBLIC
    SERVER sevidor
    OPTIONS (user 'usuario', password 'password');


    CREATE FOREIGN TABLE tabla_foranea (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    campo2 text)
    SERVER servidor
    OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'tu_tabla');
```

Y luego hacer el join entre tú tabla y  la tabla_foranea

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, al final para llenar mi tabla hecho, como usé pentaho, no era necesario consultar a las dimensiones, pero probe con el postgres fdw y creaba una tabla temporal de la que queria consultar en la otra bd.